# Symfony Environments

Tags: php, symfony

how could I change my active environment so I could access it with clean URL? At the moment if I go to my local project via http://localhost/ Symfony uses production (app.php) environment as default. I want to use development environment (app_dev.php), but I want to access it with the same URL, not with http://localhost/app_dev.php

Is it possible to change the default environment in Symfony or I should edit my Apache config? If so, what I have to add in config file?

Comment: why would you even... it's for development, if you dont know how to change it you probably want to change it for the wrong reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DEV environment is NOT intended to be used that way!
There is a lot of logging and overhead involved, and you normally use the DEV environment for debugging your project and NOT for regular use!!!

Answer (score 0):

Dev environment does not mean to be the main entry point of a symfony porject. Anyhow, yes, you can change the main environment just by editing `.htaccess` file located in the `web` directory. Replace `app.php` with `app_dev.php` in its contents. Or you can just copy-paste `app_dev.php` file contents to `app.php` file

Comment: Thank you, totally forgot the .htaccess.

Comment: great now he's going to run dev env in production... Some people just want to watch the world burn.

Comment: No worries, just getting started to work on this framework, just wanted to find out the way these environments work. I understand that dev env can't be run on live site, but just can't see why it could not be used on localhost development.